# "SELECT" command in "FROM" that have sub "SELECT" codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, subquery

For example i have query like this.

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN tgl_kondisi="2017-09-13" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as tot, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN tgl_kondisi <= "2017-09-14" THEN kl ELSE 0 end ) as sum_kl2 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
      id_kondisi as id, 
      tgl_kondisi,
      nilai_potensi_kerugian AS kl 
    FROM 
      laporan_kondisi 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
       id_sub_kondisi, 
       tgl_kondisi, 
       nilai_potensi_kerugian 
    FROM 
       laporan_kondisi ) 
    merged_table 
    GROUP BY id 
    ORDER BY cast(id as char)
```

How can i do this with query codeigniter function ?

as i know i have to

```
$this->db->select('id, SUM( CASE WHEN tgl_kondisi="2017-09-13" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as tot, SUM(CASE WHEN tgl_kondisi <= "2017-09-14" THEN kl ELSE 0 end ) as sum_kl2 ');
$this->db->from('(SELECT id_kondisi as id, tgl_kondisi,nilai_potensi_kerugian AS kl FROM laporan_kondisi UNION ALL SELECT id_sub_kondisi, tgl_kondisi, nilai_potensi_kerugian FROM laporan_kondisi ) merged_table ');
$this->db->group_by('id');
$this->db->order_by('id as char');
```

any better way so i dont have to put the query like this ?

```
$this->db->from('(SELECT id_kondisi as id,
tgl_kondisi,nilai_potensi_kerugian AS kl FROM laporan_kondisi UNION ALL
SELECT id_sub_kondisi, tgl_kondisi, nilai_potensi_kerugian FROM
laporan_kondisi ) merged_table ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view from this query:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS 
SELECT 
   id, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN tgl_kondisi="2017-09-13" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as tot, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN tgl_kondisi <= "2017-09-14" THEN kl ELSE 0 end ) as sum_kl2 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
      id_kondisi as id, 
      tgl_kondisi,
      nilai_potensi_kerugian AS kl 
    FROM 
      laporan_kondisi 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
       id_sub_kondisi, 
       tgl_kondisi, 
       nilai_potensi_kerugian 
    FROM 
       laporan_kondisi ) 
    merged_table 
    GROUP BY id 
    ORDER BY cast(id as char);
```

You could then use a simple SELECT in your CodeIgniter code:

```
$this->db->select('id, tot, sum_kl2 ');
$this->db->from('myview');
```

Also, why are you using a CAST(ID as CHAR) in your ORDER BY instead of just ORDER BY ID?

Comment: hmm this one looks good, but when i am trying to open the table view, it took about a minute. I have about 200 data.